# Database needs to be regularly updated using excel spreadsheets, but formatting is NOT uniform

Tags: sql, database, excel, ms-access

Thus far I've been manually importing/updating new records into our Access DB. Of course that's time consuming and a hassle. The reason for this is that we send our customers a template, but they don't always send us back the template with their information. Sometimes they change headers, include data in the wrong fields or maybe the wrong data...

There's nothing that I, personally, can do about that aspect of the process. Is there a way for me to develop something that will allow either myself or someone else to automatically update my DB with the click of a button (or a few)?

Comment: make a google spreadsheet with a form for it that restricts their input to allowed values only.

Comment: if they change headers and/or header text then you probably won't be able to do something like that. Even if they didn't change headers but enter wrong data (text instead of date or something) then it will just give you error if you try to enter that value into a date field. You need to have a template that requires them to enter the correct data into correct fields. @jle has a good idea!

Comment: Or just [lock the headers](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Lock-cells-in-a-worksheet-b2f833bd-9db5-48a4-9ec0-8e451ac27c3a) in Excel and keep input cells writeable.

Comment: As mentioned in the above comments, you need to improve the template; whatever rules you use for your data cleansing, you can enforce at data input time.

Comment: You could, conceivably, just set all the fields in a "Stage" table to text so it will accept any garbage sent to it, but all that means is that you will be cleaning up data in Access in between your stage table and your final table. Because your template is garbage you're going to have to clean the data at some point in your ETL.

Comment: If the input is "correct" in that the data is right for the row and column they put it in and matches the headings - I have imporeted Excel workbooks cell by cell, pulling the row description, the header description and the value for each cell into a worktable.  Then I can consolidated similar rows and columns.  Of course, then you need a process to find each new (or variant) row/column heading and decide what to do with it.  Best answer is to lock down the input template.   But if you want me to post the code for my input process, let me know.

Comment: I had the same setup / problem in a corporate environment. I got Excel files from 12 different countries back. Eventually, I wrote a VBA macro which checks the table in the Excel file. Anything that's not acceptable will be pointed out to the users and they need to fix it. If the macro fails (any errors with data entry were found) then the Excel file wouldn't be accepted. Like this there are no restrictions on the Excel file (allowing for copying and pasting large chunks). Yet, data would be checked before it is turned in. This worked (and still works) out very well for everybody.